# How to check whether a URL is downloadable or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, web-scraping, python-requests

How do I check whether the given url is downloadable or not using Python?

It should return `True` if it is downloadable else `False`

An example of a non-downloadable url: `www.google.com`

**Note:** I am not speaking about contents of the URL and saving it as a web page.

**What is a downloadable URL?**

If you redirect to a URL and if a file starts to download, then it is a downloadable url

**Example:** https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1QOmVDpd8hcVYqqUXDXf68UMDWQZP0wQV&export=download

**Note:** It downloads the stackoverflow annual survey 2019 data set.

Comment: Hello, i think you will get more help if you include what you have tried and some code that doesn't work and you need help[ with. Also explain why google is non-downloadable. What is an example of a downloadable page?

Comment: @CodeCupboard is right : what is "downloadable". In fact when you go on www.google.com, you download to your browser a bunch of files. I think that what you mean is check the return type of a requested url. Am i right ?

Comment: @CodeCupboard Plz check my EDIT

Comment: @yAzou Plz check my Edit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done in using the popular requests library

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.com'
headers=requests.head(url).headers
downloadable = 'attachment' in headers.get('Content-Disposition', '')
```

[Content Disposition Header reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

Answer (score 3):

So I tried searching for a better way, the site link which I was checking was a bit tricky
most stackoverflow answers mentioned about using head request to get response header, but the site I was checking returned 404 error.When I use get request the whole file is downloaded before outputing the header.My friend suggested me a solution of using the parameter `stream=True` and that really got worked.

```
import requests 
r = requests.get(link, stream=True)
print(r.headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

On HTTP protocol level itself, there is no distinction between downloadable and non-downloadable URL. There is an HTTP request and there is a subsequent response. Response body can be a binary file, HTML, image etc..

You can just request the HTTP response header and look for `Content-Type:` and decide whether you want to consider that content-type as downloadable or non-downloadable.

Comment: check `Content-Disposition`, too

Answer (score 0):

Downloadable files must have Content-Length in headers :

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

try:
    print(r.headers['content-length'])
except:
    print("Not Downloadable")
```